# XmlHttpRequest in Symfony2

Tags: ajax, symfony, xmlhttprequest, request, symfony-2.1

Here follows my problem. In a *Symfony2.1* controller I receive an *Ajax* call. If I use the `Request` object I'm not able to get the sent param. If I use the PHP `_REQUEST` object the param is found!
I can confirm that the request is *XHR*, if it matters.
Here is my code:

```
public function savedataAction(Request $request){  
  if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
  echo 'Ajax Call';

  $param1 = $request->request->get('myParam'); // Nothing is returned, but $request is obviosly not null
  $param2 = $_REQUEST['myParam']; // The value is given

  ....
}
```

Any idea?

PS: If helps, notice that the AJAX call is sent by the file uploader jQuery plugin provided by [Valums](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Normally its:**

```
// retrieve GET and POST variables respectively
$request->query->get('foo');
$request->request->get('bar', 'default value if bar does not exist');
```

Look here are the fundamentels.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html

**Edit:**

`$request` in your case is only filled when you send the form from the Symfony2 site. It is possible, that the CSRF protection block the request.

Try this in your controller to get the Request object:

```
$request = $this->get('request');
```

http://symfony2forum.org/threads/5-Using-Symfony2-jQuery-and-Ajax

Comment: Ops, sorry! I wrote the code wrong in my example... it is $request->request. I'm going to correct my question! But the problem remains!

Comment: I have edited my answer. The problem is, that you have to access the request object in another way. The CSRF protection block external requests when they not come from a valid form.

Comment: I found the problem. The param is in $request->query->get('myParam'). I was quite sure that the method used was POST and not GET! Really strange!

Comment: I know! But I have to complete this job! I'm going to have a lot of rest! Thanks a lot!